# Error loading the page after deploying to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created an web application. It runs perfectly in localhost. when i deployed to Google App Engine, it works but one particular page is not running. It does not throw any exceptions but shows ERROR : NOT FOUND (404)

I understand this is file not found error but don't know why is this is error shown. even when i deploy it shows "application deployed successfully!".

can anyone help me to fix it.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your code (server and client), and give the URL please (second thought, for 404 the URL would be useless).

Comment: Post you url handler, and tell us which url is giving the 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with which slashes you use in your code when using paths and links. In windows, the backslash '\' is used, meanwhile Linux uses forward slashes '/'. Often this isin't an issue but it does cause problems once in a while. Also this explains why it would work fine on your localhost, but not once you deploy it.